# What's the relationship between res.partner and res.user?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8

I am new to odoo v8 and i am not able to understand the relationship between res_partner and res_users tables and also with hr_employee table are they all related?

Answer (score 4):

The relationship between `res.partner` and `res.user` is that **`res.user` inherits from `res.partner` using an inheritance type called "Delegation Inheritance"** (see [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#reference-orm-inheritance)).

Because of "Delegation Inheritance" every `res.user` record has a mandatory internal connection to a corresponding `res.partner` record using a field `partner_id`. What is this connection all about is to directly use all the fields of `res.partner` to store data shared by `res.user` and `res.partner` (i.e. name, phone, etc... if for example you refer to phone property of a record of `res.user` you'll get the value stored in the corresponding `res.partner` record) so `res.user` has to define fewer number of fields on it's own, like password, login, etc..

Note also that because of this relation `res.user` can NOT exist in the system without corresponding `res.partner`, it's why every `res.user` has one, but nonetheless `res.partner` can exist without `res.user`.

Answer (score 2):

1. hr.employee have m21 with res.users (user_id)
   [image]
2. res.users have m21 with res.partner(partner_id)
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually only res.users has a "real" relationship to res.partner, because with every user odoo will create a partner (per default no customer and no supplier). this partner will be used e.g. for emails and the followers system in odoo.

But you can have partners without users, too. That will be a normal partner, for defining customers and suppliers.

And finally there is the employee. You can set a user on it. If i recall right, the user will be used for attendances and timesheets.